# smart coffee maker multiple bean reservoirs

Tags: beans, coffee-machines

Is there a smart coffee maker (perhaps google assistant compatible?) that has multiple bean reservoirs. Large water reservoir would be a nice to have.

- automatic coffee maker
- would be nice if it were google assistant compatible
- multiple bean reservoirs

No milk varieties needed, but if it is possible it’s welcome :)